# Rotate single image in array of images using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

I have an array of images. Each iteration displays an image and a button. I want to rotate the image 90 degrees by clicking the button. I prefer to do it using jQuery.

Loop code (PHP with Twig):

```
{% for key, file in image_files %}
    <div class="image-box">
        <img class="patient-image" data-uniqueid="{{ key }}" src="/{{ src_path }}{{ file }}">
        <p>
            <a class="rotate-btn btn" data-imageid="{{ key }}">Rotate</a>
        </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The data attribute is used to store the element's index value by passing the key value to `data-imageid` in the button in order to link it to the image which assigns the same key value to `data-uniqueid`. On inspection, the values match for each button and image.

Here's the jQuery to retrieve `data-` values:

```
$( '.rotate-btn' ).on('click', function() {

    // get value of data-imageid from button
    var id = $( this ).data().imageid;

    // get value of data-uniqueid from image
    var imageid = $('.patient-image').data().uniqueid;

});
```

When I click the rotate button on the first image, the values of `id` and `imageid` match. But on the second image the value of `id` is correct but the value of `imageid` is incorrect. It matches the first image value and not the image clicked.

Any help identifying where my error(s) might be is appreciated. I am uncertain whether I am approaching this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var imageid = $('.patient-image').data().uniqueid;
```

should be

```
var imageid = $(this).parent().siblings('.patient-image').data().uniqueid;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works by returning the correct value from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not tested but will, I hope, help. There should be no need to use IDs to target elements as you are trying to do - simply use sibling and parent selectors in conjunction with `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`. I believe jQuery has it's own methods for this but I cannot advise as to what they are.

The idea here is that you obtain a reference to all the buttons used to rotate the images and assign a generic event handler to each. The event handler when invoked clears any previously assigned `rotated` classes and assigns this css class to the button's sibling image.

```
{% for key, file in image_files %}
    <div class='image-box'>
        <img class='patient-image' src='/{{ src_path }}{{ file }}'>
        <p>
            <a class='rotate-btn btn'>Rotate</a>
        </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

a tested version

```
    for( $i=0; $i < 10; $i++ ){
        echo "
<div class='image-box'>
    <img class='patient-image' src='/images/homer_2.png'>
    <p>
        <a href='#' class='rotate-btn btn'>Rotate</a>
    </p>
</div>";
    }
```

[image: Source image used in tests]

```
    <style>
        .image-box{clear:none; display:inline-block; margin:1rem; float:left;}
        .rotate-btn{padding:1rem;border:1px solid black;background:whitesmoke;cursor:pointer}
        img{ transform:rotate(0deg); transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;  }
        .rotated{ transform:rotate(90deg) }
    </style>


    <script>
        Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'a.rotate-btn' ) ).forEach( bttn=>{

            bttn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                /* if other \"rotated\" images are to revert to their original orientation, else remove this or comment it out */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('img.rotated') ).forEach( img=>{img.classList.remove('rotated') }) 

                /* apply the css class to perform the rotation */
                let img=this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('img');
                    img.classList.add( 'rotated' );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[image: The resultant display]
The result:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using the jQuery function `$('.patient-image')` *without context*, you will retrieve **all** elements having the class `patient-image`. When you apply `.data()` to the selection of elements, it will be used on **the first one**. That's why the value is only right the first time.

**I think what you want is the element closest to the button clicked.**

```
var imageid = $(this).closest('.patient-image').data().uniqueid;
```

is therefore my suggestion. *In case you are only using the "id" and "uniqueid" for identifying the corresponding element, it should become obsolete using this approach.*

I'd also suggest using `$(...).data('uniqueid')` instead of getting all the data everytime.

**To rotate the corresponding image, use the following snippet:**

```
$( '.rotate-btn' ).on('click', function() {
  $(this)
    .closest('.patient-image')
    .css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)')
});
```

Comment: There's a problem with your code: `$(this).closest('.patient-image')` won't match the expected element here, because '.patient-image' isn't a 'parent' of the current element. See my answer for a working element match.

Comment: Thanks! The snippet works. @schellmax is correct about `$(this).closest('.patient-image')` not working.